# iterate through a result set and add it a arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I want to iterate through the result set and add them in a list

```
final ArrayList<Integer> i = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
try{
  while(resultSet.next()) {
  resultSet.getInt(1);
  resultSet.getInt(2);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29 to add elements to the ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (resultSet.next()) {
    list.add(resultSet.getInt(1));
    list.add(resultSet.getInt(2));
}
```